# How to find a specific tweet in its context?

Tags: twitter, search, tweet

Via a direct link I found [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jocxy/status/14740179398959104) dated 14 Dec 2010. Now I wanted to see the tweets this user sent just before and after this specific message so I made an advanced search:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Ajocxy%20since%3A2010-12-13%20until%3A2010-12-15&src=typd
```

(date between 2010-12-13 and 2010-12-15 and the user name) but this specific tweet (the one I found through the direct link) is missing in the results. (A lot of other tweets that are related are included in the results).

Why is that?

Does Twitter offer an option to go to a user's next or previous tweet in order by time?

Comment: Web app requests are off-topic, so I removed that portion of the question.  If you find out that there is no way to do so natively on Twitter, you can ask for a third party solution on [softwarerecs.SE].

Comment: @pnuts No I didn't but now I have and it is still not there. These two tweets https://twitter.com/jocxy/status/14740442071437312 and https://twitter.com/jocxy/status/14739555609481216 are posted just before and after, if you look at their timestamps as well as their content, and they show up in the search results.

Comment: Yes it might be that. The direct linked tweet contains a NSFW-word but seriously, you could probably probably find that word in a lot of articles in Washington Post or The Guardian. Edit: yes you can, around 1000 times in The Guardian and around 500 in WaPo.